# Java XML Parsing into a List and Grabbing Nodes

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML document and I need to put every child in to a List and then once it is in a List I need to be able to grab a specific child node from an index in the List. My code so far only grabs every child node but I don't know how to put it in a List, looping through it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
      DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

       try {
            URL url = new URL ("http://feeds.cdnak.neulion.com/fs/nhl/mobile/feeds/data/20140401.xml");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
             // use the factory to create a documentbuilder
             DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

             // create a new document from input stream
             Document doc = builder.parse(is);        // get the first element
    Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
    System.out.println(element);

    // get all child nodes
    NodeList nodes = element.getChildNodes();


    // print the text content of each child
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println("" + nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
    } } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Comment: If you use JAXB, you wouldn't need any loop.

Comment: You've already got your Nodes in a NodeList, and can grab any element via the NodeList method `item(int i)` which you're already using.